# Animate arrows with CSS only

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

If you check the [Toshiba's website](http://lifenology.toshiba.co.jp/lifenology/en/index.htm), there's a small mouse icon with moving arrows. Apparently, they're animating it like so:

```
function iconTop() {
$(".icon_tween").animate({
    opacity: 0,
    marginTop: "15px"
}, 1e3, function () {
    $(".icon_tween").css({
        marginTop: 0,
        opacity: 1
    }), iconTop()
})
}
```

.. is it possible to animate exactly the same with CSS only?

Comment: Not bothered to click the link, but I'm still gonna guess: Yes. They're animating position (better done with transform: translate() than margin-top) and opacity, both very well-supported by CSS3 animations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use `translate` instead of margin top, so that it would be more independent of your element layout and more performant.

```
@-webkit-keyframes arrow-jump {
  0%   { opacity: 0;}
  100% { opacity: 1; 
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
    -o-transform: translateY(10px);
    transform: translateY(10px);
    }  
}
#arrow {
  -webkit-animation: arrow-jump 1s infinite;
  -moz-animation:    arrow-jump 1s infinite
  -o-animation:      arrow-jump 1s infinite;
  animation:         arrow-jump 1s infinite;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/PHUf4/163/)

Answer (score 3):

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.arrow {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left:-20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-size: contain;
  
}

.bounce {
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}

/* Scroll down indicator (bouncing) */
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px); } }
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0); }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px); }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-15px); } }
@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0); }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px); }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px); } }
```

```html
<div class="arrow bounce">
```

Comment: great ...it helped me lots.can u tell me what type of data is in background-image: url().....???cause it is too long ...

Answer (score 2):

Sure, why not?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/98W5U/3/

Code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes toshiba {
    from{
        margin-top:0;
        opacity: 1;       
    }
    to{
        margin-top: 30px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
div {
    -webkit-animation: toshiba 2s linear infinite;
}
```

Remember about all browser prefixes and don't expect it to work on older browsers (IE, huh!).

**EDIT**
Here's the arrows as well: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vulpCod3z/U6f8k/)